# Where clause on Linq Extension method

Tags: c#, linq, join, where-clause

I have the following lambda expression:

```
query = query.Join( SecondTableSource,
table1 => new
{
    table1 .Field1,
    table1 .Field2
},
table2 => new
{
    table2 .Field1,
    table2 .Field2
},
( table1 , table2 ) => table1 ) ;
```

As you can see I am only returning results from the first table but I need to filter out results by a column in table2. How would I go about doing that but still only returning 
`IQueryable<table1>`?

Thanks!

Here is the original code I am trying to convert:

```
query = from table1 in Model.Table1s
    join table2 in Model.Table2s
        on new
        {
            table1.field1,
            table1.field2
        }
    equals
        new
        {
            table2.field1,
            table2.Part
        }
    where table2.field.StartsWith( criteria.value )
    select table1;
```

I think I must not have converted correctly because the first two answers posted (that is all that is posted at the time i am writing this) should work but both only return one result when I am expecting 4 (as was returned by original query).

Comment: Could you give some sample data so we can understand what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

Filter the table2 before can't you?

```
query = query.Join(SecondTableSource.Where(table2 => table2.MyFieldToFilter == condition),
                   table1 => ...,
                   ...);
```

Comment: Hmm that seems pretty easy, let me give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like it should work but it doesn't return the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option if you have a more complicated query...

```
IEnumerable<MyType1> result = table1.Join(table2,
        t1 => new { t1.Field1, t1.Field2 },
        t2 => new { t2.Field1, t2.Field2 },
        (t1, t2) => new { table1 = t1, table2 = t2 }).
    Where(joinedResults => joinedResults.table2 == //condition).
    Select(filteredResults => filteredResults.table1);
```